# WordPress page shows 404 when adding to URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm adding rewrite rules to my PHP script which is included in a WordPress page with the permalink **kb**

So I can visit domain.com/kb and the page is displayed.

```
function wdm_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^kb/([^/]+)/?$', 'kb?kb_cat=$matches[1]&kb_seq=1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'wdm_add_rewrite_rules');
```

But when I visit the page with additional strings in the url, I get a 404.

So when I visit domain.com/kb is shows the correct page, and then visiting domain.com/kb/84/92, it shows a 404

I just need to be able to read the additional url params in my PHP script, such as `$_GET["kb_cat"]`

Comment: Please try adding rewrite rules in .htaccess file

Comment: have you enabled mod rewrite on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function wdm_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^kb$', 'index.php?kb_cat=$matches[1]&kb_seq=1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'wdm_add_rewrite_rules');
```

to take it a step further and use the parameters:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "kb_cat";
    $vars[] = "kb_seq";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

and then load a custom template file:

```
function include_custom_template($template){

    if(get_query_var('kb_cat') && get_query_var('kb_seq')){
        $template = get_template_directory() ."/my-custom-template.php";
    } 
   
    return $template;    
}

add_filter('template_include', 'include_custom_template');
```

Once adding to your `functions.php` go to Settings > Permalinks and hit 'save changes' to reset the flush rules

Comment: I just added the `add_query_vars_filter` function and flushed the permalinks but I'm still getting a 404. I don't know whether adding the code into functions.php will make a difference as i have a php script with the page content on which i then use an include plugin in my wordpress page

Comment: are you pulling your template correctly for the custom page?

Comment: I am using a plugin called "IncludeMe" which does a PHP include

Comment: what file is the 'kb' page going to be?

Comment: `kb` is the page slug in wordpress

Comment: right, but are you loading a custom template for it?

Comment: I have a standard wordpress page, and in the content is `[includeme file="api/tools/knowledgebase.php"]` which uses this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/include-me/

Comment: and you added this function to your functions.php?

Comment: yeah, in functions.php and also tried directly in the custom PHP script

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
function wdm_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^kb\/([^\/]+)\/?([^\/]+)$', 'kb?kb_cat=$matches[1]&kb_seq=1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'wdm_add_rewrite_rules');
```

You can check the regular expression on https://regex101.com/  or any other websites like this online for the matches

Comment: Still just a 404 using this code

Comment: Goto Permalink -> setting and click on Save without modifying anything in the page. It could be pretty url function issue from wordpress default.